# Cannot content port Page Templates in 2013 SP1

Tags: content-porter-2013-sp1

I'm using content porter 2013 SP1. I'm able to content port all other item types except Page Templates. When I try to browse the Page Templates folder in CP, it shows an error message like "Sequence contains no matching elements". As an alternate, I'm adding the PTs to bundles and then exporting & importing the bundles.

We had similar issue in CME, which got fixed later  by installing the Legacy Templates pack. I would like to know if anyone else has faced this kind of issue in Content Porter 2013. If so, what could be the resolution for this. 
Kindly let me know if you need more info. Appreciate your help.

screen shot attached for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As expected, the issue is related to Legacy Templates Pack. It is working now, it is a DB fix. We have missed updating the sub_type value for few PTs in DB.